# Access ASP.NET control in parent GridView in from OnRowDataBound event in child GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, parent-child

I have the following markup snippet on my ASP.NET page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAppID" runat="server" />
                <asp:GridView id="gvChild" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvChild_RowDataBound" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to access the value assigned to the `hfAppID` hidden field control in the `gvChild_RowDataBound` event

```
protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //need to access the hfAppId hidden field control from parent here
    }
}
```

How would I accomplish this task?

Comment: why are you trying to do this there?May u explain your finale goal?to setup an id or reference from parent to child?

Comment: I need the value to filter property collections within the DataItem of the child `GridView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Parent.FindControl**.

```
protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var gvChild = sender as GridView;    
        var hfAppID = gvChild.Parent.FindControl("hfAppID") as HiddenField;
        var id = hfAppID.Value;
    }
}
```